# How to convert elapsed days since January 1st year 0000 to Python elapsed seconds since January 1st year 1970

Tags: python, matlab, datetime

I have a float that comes from Matlab, expressed as a number of days elapsed since January 1st of year 0000.

Let's use `739183.392799916` as an example.

In Matlab, `datestr(739183.392799916 ,'dd/mm/yyyy-HH:MM:SS.FFF')` gives `24/10/2023-09:25:37.913`

I'm working in Python, so I want to convert this value to a number of seconds since epoch (January 1st of year 1970), same standard as `time.time()`

So I did:

```
def matlab_time_to_python_float(matlab_time: float) -> float:
    # Matlab standard is days since 1er Janvier 0000 heure 00:00:00
    # Python standard is seconds since 1er Janvier 1970 00:00:00
    from datetime import datetime, date
    
    matlab_ref = date(1, 1, 1)
    python_ref = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0).date()
    delta = python_ref - matlab_ref
    
    python_day = matlab_time - delta.days
    
    seconds_in_a_day = 24*3600
    python_time = python_day*seconds_in_a_day
    
    return python_time
```

And additionnaly, to output the time:

```
def python_float_to_str(python_time_float: float) -> str:
    # Use localtime, not gmtime. With gmtime, we get UTC time without timezone/summer/winter
    import time
    local = time.localtime(python_time_float)
    millisecondes = int(round((python_time_float - int(python_time_float)),3) * 1000)
    return time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y ', local) + f"{local.tm_hour:02d}:{local.tm_min:02d}:{local.tm_sec:02d}.{millisecondes:03d}"
```

Now, when I do:

```
as_str = ( python_float_to_str( matlab_time_to_python_float( 739183.392799916 ) ) )
print(as_str)
```

It outputs `25/10/2024 11:25:37.913`. Different than Matlab's `24/10/2023-09:25:37.913` by **1 year, one day and 2 hours**....

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? The code is very simple, I can't see what's wrong.

Comment: Matlab_ref should be `date(0, 1, 1)` though that gives an error?

Comment: Is Matlab's `24/10/2023-09:25:37.913` expressed in UTC, or in local time? If local time, which timezone?

Comment: I guess Matlab's `0000` works like ISO and means "the year before 1 CE", i.e. 1 BCE. But your code measures from 1st Jan of 1 CE itself (`date(1, 1, 1)`) so that will be where your 1 year discrepancy comes from.

Comment: @slothrop: Thanks you. This Héloïse and the other post mine's marked as duplicate of also.

Comment: @slothrop MATLAB's datenum (the floating point number) and datestr (the string version of this) are agnostic to time zone. They are simply generic time scales that are neither UTC nor local time. Their meaning is up to the programmer depending on how they are used in code.